# Primary source for Ambedkar's claims on Veda Vyas Smriti

Tags: scripture, smriti, vyasa, cows

I'm looking for the primary source for the following claim made by Ambedkar ([link](https://scroll.in/article/812645/read-what-ambedkar-wrote-on-why-brahmins-started-worshipping-the-cow-and-gave-up-eating-beef)).

I tried finding the text [here](https://archive.org/details/vyasa-smriti-m-n-dutt/page/n5/mode/2up) but I am not able to find it. Does someone know the exact verse of this text in the Veda Vyas Smriti ?

> This new theory receives support from the Hindu Shastras. The Veda
> Vyas Smriti contains the following verse which specifies the
> communities which are included in the category of Antyajas and the
> reasons why they were so included
>
> “The Charmakars (Cobbler), the Bhatta (Soldier), the Bhilla, the
> Rajaka (washerman), the Puskara, the Nata (actor), the Vrata, the
> Meda, the Chandala, the Dasa, the Svapaka, and the Kolika – these are
> known as Antyajas as well as others who eat cow’s flesh.”

Answer (score 1):

here it is:

http://www.astrojyoti.com/pdfs/DevanagariFiles/02Vyasa_Smriti.pdf

Chapter 1 shlokas 11 and 12.

Comment: Great, thanks. But where is the word "Antyaja" mentioned ? Reading the whole page gives a totally different meaning that what Ambedkar claims.

Comment: the hook symbol between  ete and ntyaja is an avagraha - stands for an a sound that is not pronounced.  I haven't had a chance to look into Ambedkar's interpretation. @rajesh

Comment: @Rajesh why bother Ambedkar had no or limited knowledge of Hindu texts and certainly not any understanding of them.